# parser.add_argument: error: unrecognized arguments: True

Tags: python, argparse

I have a program in python 2.7, which has a line of code:

```
parser.add_argument('--skip_train', default=False, help='skip training', action='store_true')
```

This code tells the program to run with training by default. But now I want to implement it without training since the training has been done. So I type in the prompt:

```
python myprogame.py --skip_train True
```

But this gives an error message:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: True
```

What should type in the prompt command to implement the program?

Answer (score 4):

When you use `action='store_true'`, you shouldn't provide a value for the `--skip_train` option. Just do:

```
python myprogame.py --skip_train
```